# Android is returning a String after 'AsyncTask'

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-internet

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class JsonController 
{
    private JSONObject inputData, json, finalResult;
    private String authentication;

    public JsonController()
    {
        json = new JSONObject();

        inputData = new JSONObject();
    }

    public void createAuthentication(String userName, String apiKey)
    {
        authentication = "";
    }


    public void setModel(String model) throws JSONException
    {
        json.put("model",model);
    }

    public void setData(String id, String deviceType) throws JSONException
    {
        inputData.put(id, deviceType);
    }



    public void getPrediction()
    {
        new sendJSon().execute("");
            return finalResult.toString();
    }




    private class sendJSon extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(authentication);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            try {
                  // Add your data
                  json.put("input_data", inputData);

                  StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                  httppost.setEntity(se); 

                  // Execute HTTP Post Request
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(
                                  response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                  String jsonString = reader.readLine();
                  JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonString);

                  finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  Log.d("Error here", "Error is here",e);
              }


            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

This code always crashes in `getPrediction()` because of `NulPointerException`. `NullPointerException` is because the Async task take time to generate the String, and the `getPrediction()` method returns the string before it is ready. All of these methods get called via external classes, so how can I solve this?

Comment: onPostExecute(), Google that! Here you will find a reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Which line do you get NPE? Post `logcat` and you are returning string from a `void` type function..

Comment: Post your `onPostExecute()` method. @FlowOverStack.

Comment: getPrediction is void. It can not return a String

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether `ASYNCTASK` has finished execution or not until then you can halt the returning of string from method `getPrediction();`

```
if(CLASSOBJECT!= null && CLASSOBJECT.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
            //DO NOT RETURN ANY VALUE
        }else{
//RETURN VALUE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the `String` in your `doInBackground` method as :

```
  return jsonString;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed

```
outNullPointerException is because the Async task take time to generate the
String, and the getPrediction() method returns the string before it is ready.
```

You should run your network based operation in thread in `doInBackground` and then join that thread. Then you should call `getPrediction()` `in onPostExecute()`. Thus you'll have the data before the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPostExecute()` instead. `onPostExecute()` receives the return value from `doInBackground()` after it finishes. From there you can do whatever needs to be done with your result.

If `onPostExecute()` isn't flexible enough for you, consider using a CountDownLatch to stall your main code execution until AsyncTask returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sample code which you can implement

```
public interface AsyncResponseHandler {
    public String resultCall(String resultStr);
}

public class MyMainClass extends Activity implements AsyncResponseHandler{

    public void doProcessing(){
        new AsynTasker(this).execute(null); //here this is instance of AsyncResponseHandler
    }

    @Override
    public String resultCall(String resultStr) {
        //here you will receive results from your async task after execution and you can carry out whatever process you want to do.
    }
}

public class AsynTasker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    AsyncResponseHandler handler=null;
    public AsynTasker(AsyncResponseHandler handler){
      this.handler = handler
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         // do your processing
         return resultString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        this.handler.resultCall(result);
    }

}
```